# VBA How to combine two codes into one and use 'Enter' to execute?

Tags: vba, excel, button

I'm doing a project where you have random maths equations and solve them and then track them.

I currently have two buttons where one is a 'start' button that tracks how long it takes you to solve an equation and also resets all past tracked equations.

```
Private Sub btnStart_Click()

'Starts counting down from 11'
varCounter = 11

'Clear cells from the range'
Range("A11:K22").Clear

'Making Start time appear in the cell'
Range("G10") = "Start Time = "

'Showing the time started to do the first question'
Range("H10").Value = Now()
Range("H10").NumberFormat = "mm.ss"

'Making Difference appear in the cell'
Range("I10") = "Difference ="

'Clearing and making the typing go to the answer cell'
Range("H5").Activate
Range("H5") = " "

End Sub
```

The other button is a 'check' button that will check if the answer written for the equation was correct and tracks it in cells below.

```
Private Sub btnCheck_Click()

'Emoticons for right and wrong answers'
If Range("a3") * Range("c3") = Range("e3") Then
    Range("f3").Font.Size = 36
    Range("f3") = ChrW(&H263A)
Else
    Range("f3") = ChrW(&H2639)
End If

'Get the time'
Range("J" & varCounter).Value = Now()
Range("J" & varCounter).NumberFormat = "mm.ss"

'Finding the time when answered and the differnece'
Time1 = Range("J" & varCounter).Value
Time2 = Range("J" & varCounter - 1).Value
Range("K" & varCounter).Value = Time1 - Time2
Range("K" & varCounter).NumberFormat = ("mm.ss")

'Make the answers go down the colum'
Range("a" & varCounter & ":f" & varCounter).Value = Range("a3:f3").Value
varCounter = varCounter + 1

'clearing and making the typing go to the answer cell'
Range("H5").Activate
Range("H5") = " "

'Clearing Cell'
Range("E3") = ""


  If IsEmpty(Range("d20")) Then

Else

Range("D10:o100").Clear

varCounter = 11
Range("n10") = Time
Range("n10").NumberFormat = "mm:ss"
Range("K10") = "Difference ="
Range("G10") = "Start Time = "
End If

End Sub
```

How can I combine these two together and also make it so that I only need to enter the answer and press enter without any need for buttons?

Comment: Consider using event handlers -- they allow you to run code when specific target cells are changed.  Check out this link to see if that 's the sort of approach you want to try: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh211482(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: It looks interesting but a bit too confusing for me.

Comment: Yes, it does seem confusing at first, but the basic idea is that you put an event function like "Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)" into the code for that particular sheet, and then whenever the user changes something on the sheet it returns the range they changed in the "target" variable.  You then write code based on that target range change. By the way, that link I supplied includes a workbook with working routines that can be downloaded.

Comment: There is a problem that there is no clue to start the timer.

Comment: What is a clue?